# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while reading data from file android

Tags: android, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, bufferedinputstream

I am uploading video using `multipartentity` in chunks, to upload I am reading data from file. In the first loop I am able to read data, but in the next loop it is getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Exception :

```
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1024;
> regionStart=1024; regionLength=1024

I am reading 1024 bytes in every loop.

totalSize = 441396

offset starts from 0

chunkSize = 1024
```

My code:

```
do {
    currentChunkSize = totalSize - offset > chunkSize ? chunkSize : totalSize - offset;

    String urlString = "http://capmem.omsoftware.co/Event/UploadVideo?" +
                            "callback=localJsonpCallback&" +
                            "filename="+ filename +"&" +
                            "ext="+ exten +"&" +
                            "totalsize="+ size +"&" +
                            "EventID="+ eventid +"&" +
                            "UserID="+ userid +"&" +
                            "comment="+ coment +"&" +
                            "VideoLength="+ videolength +
                            "&chunk=" + currentChunkSize;

    httppost1 = new HttpPost(urlString);

    byte[] currentBytes = new byte[currentChunkSize];
    buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    buf.read(currentBytes, offset, currentChunkSize);

    offset += currentChunkSize;

    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    reqEntity.addPart("videofile", new ByteArrayBody(currentBytes, "application/octet-stream", filename));

    httppost1.setEntity(reqEntity);
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost1);
    int resCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

} while(totalSize != offset);
```

Getting Exception in

```
buf.read(currentBytes, offset, currentChunkSize);
```

Answer (score 2):

The offset parameter is the offset into currentBytes you want to write, not the offset into the stream.  Since currentBytes is of length currentChunkSize, if offset is anything other than 0 you'll go past the end of the array.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I could not understood your explanation.
Can you please explain in code.?

Comment: @user2085965: Gabe meant to say that the `offset` value you are passing to your `read` method points to the starting index of your array to which the read bytes are being copied; the `BufferedInputStream` remembers and continues to read from the point it has previously read. If you want your array to contain only the current chunk, you must replace `buf.read(currentBytes, offset, currentChunkSize);` with `buf.read(currentBytes, 0, currentChunkSize);`

Answer (score 0):

your `currentChunkSize` is always `1024` since your only check is

```
currentChunkSize = totalSize - offset > chunkSize ? chunkSize : totalSize - offset;
```

you never modify the `totalSize`. You need to know how many bytes are left to determine the chunk size you need.

Try adding

```
totalSize = totalSize-currentChunkSize;
```

also you can change the while condition to

```
while(totalSize!=0)
```

and even better to change it to a pre-condition loop instead of the do-while (the file might be empty)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Same error in the same line of code.

Comment: well, I also notice you are opening the buffer on every iteration without closing it after... This might cause a problem also